# making a folder to become a root folder via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

got myself in a little dev jam... wondering if any can help... it has to do with .htaccess , modifying url's...

i got an example...

foobar.com/foo/index2.php

how can i get the url to always point to foobar.com/index2.php
(so that "foo"  becomes the root folder  )

i read it has to to with the .htaccess and server permissions...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

kind of a newbee,  can someone  point me to the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

In your root .htaccess (a level above `foo`) place this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!foo/).*)$ /foo/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really good in htaccess but i have some manual solution for this ... it's rewriting the link to make the user if he go this link which you can identify it as subfolder he will open the following link ... here's an example

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder/subfolder
RewriteRule folder/subfolder http://localhost/website/file2.php
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder/subfolder
RewriteRule folder/subfolder http://localhost/website/folder
```

not that this will give more secured website as nobody will understand that how it's really working over your website

Answer (score 0):

[You don't a actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

Try using `mod_redirect` instead:

```
RedirectMatch ^/foo/(.*) /$1
```